# Video introductorio para SOes

Tags: discusión, promoción-del-sitio

espero que todos se encuentren bien, ando con ganas de hacer un video pequeño (3-4 minutos a lo mucho) explicando diversos detalles de nuestra querida comunidad, estas ganas vienen gracias a un video que hice para promocionar al [Xamarin Dev Days](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PVsDS2IfMvA) que se dará en la comunidad académica Microsoft de donde vengo: UPAOnet {Trujillo, Perú}

Me gustaría contar con su apoyo con ideas sobre qué cosas debería mostrar en el video promocional de StackOverflow en Español, realizamos un brainstorming de lo que saldrá un guión/storyboard/musiquita de fondo, un video creado entre todos!

Me interno un día a producir esto y espero que sea de utilidad para que el sitio siga creciendo, eso sí dejo en claro que el video estará libre de publicidad ya que lo que buscamos es crecer y no lucrar :D

**Las ideas recogidas serán procesadas el 16 de Octubre, así que tenemos tiempo para colaborar! Venga vamos!**

## Edición:

**Estado actual al 25 Octubre 2016: En progreso**

En primer lugar, pido disculpas por la demora, entre situaciones personales y familiares he estado con poco tiempo frente a mi laptop, en segundo lugar, me encuentro en la producción del primer video para nuestra comunidad, en base a la respuesta de @JuanM, tenemos lo siguiente:

> Video 1: Intro a la comunidad - quienes somos, razones de existir,
> modelo de comunidad a. Stack Overflow: historia, cómo llegamos a ser,
> la necesidad de abrir un sitio de habla-hispana para ayudar a
> desarrolladores que prefieren interacciones en español.
>
> b. Razones de visitar al sitio: 100% gratuito, información
> proporcionada por otros desarrolladores globales, oportunidad de
> aprender de otros expertos en tecnologías diferentes, ¿tienes una
> pregunta/problema? -> SOes -> solución.
>
> c. Repositorio de información accesible en español: no somos un foro
> de discusión, formula buenas preguntas y recibe respuestas buenas y
> especificas, busca entre miles de preguntas y respuestas, contesta y
> edita el contenido del sitio para ayudarnos a mantener un sitio con
> relevancia y precisión alta.

Tan pronto como tenga el video subido a YouTube, estaré actualizando con el link para que puedan visualizar y comentar, todo feedback será bien recibido :D La idea es mejorar y seguir mejorando :D

Comment: ¡Me gusta la idea! Pero, ¿cual es la meta de este video? ¿Queremos educar,  atraer atención, o alguna otra cosa? Al contestar esta pregunta la cosa se pone más clara en mi opinion.

Comment: 1. Dar a conocer que existe SOes. 2.Educar a los nuevos mostrando un "tour" de iniciación (que vaya un poquito más allá del tour que tenemos implementado en el sitio) 3. Hacer crecer esta hermandad que hay entre los que andamos por estos lares :D

Comment: Hmm... yo creo que depende como se haga. Es decir, si se hace bien puede ser super positivo, pero como no salga bien puede perjudicarnos... es como el binario, no hay termino medio. 

Quizás si se acepta la propuesta (que no niego que sea una buena iniciativa, aunque la veo muy "binaria") lo ideal sería que los que sabéis podáis darle un cable a la hora de hacerlo, orientaciones etc para "bordarlo".

Comment: y aquí es cuando las cosas se ponen interesantes :D la comunidad colabora y la idea se mejora :D

Comment: @Dianne sería interesante que uno de los vídeos los diga una mujer, ¿qué piensas?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, dices de que yo le ponga voz al vídeo? XDD, no me veo haciéndolo la verdad... se me hace muy extraño xD (además para ser mujer, mi voz es de las graves y el acento que tengo es algo basto). Seguro que hay alguna otra chica con una voz mas amigable xD

Comment: ¿Alguna actualización del tema?

Comment: hasta el momento somos 3 personas que deseamos "narrar" en el video: @LuiggiMendoza, a ti PaperBirdMaster y quien escribe. Siento que necesitamos más ideas de cómo iniciar el video, JuanM nos ha dado una excelente organización, ahora sólo nos hace falta ponerle el contenido dentro de cada punto :D por eso he extendido la fecha hasta el 16 para que más personas interesadas puedan colaborar, siento que luego vamos por un trello.com para colaborar entre quienes estamos y le damos con todo el power 2.0!!! Saludos hermano

Comment: ¿ya están listos los vídeos? y ¿donde se pueden ver?

Comment: ¿Qué ha pasado con esto? ¿Quedó en el olvido?

Comment: buena pregunta @JheymanMejia , a lo mucho que avancé, tengo un audio y un script de dicho audio, está para buscarlos y te lo paso si deseas colaborar con ello :D

Comment: Claro, tengo cierta experiencia para trabajar con audios. En lo que les pueda ser útil, lo haré con gusto.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Propongo tener una serie de videos (de 3-4 minutos cada uno) narrados por nuestro propio @FredyFX y otros que quieran ayudar.

**Video 1**: Intro a la comunidad - quienes somos, razones de existir, modelo de comunidad 

**a.** Stack Overflow: historia, cómo llegamos a ser, la necesidad de abrir un sitio de habla-hispana para ayudar a desarrolladores que prefieren interacciones en español.


**b.** Razones de visitar al sitio: 100% gratuito, información proporcionada por otros desarrolladores globales, oportunidad de aprender de otros expertos en tecnologías diferentes, ¿tienes una pregunta/problema? -> SOes -> solución.


**c.** Repositorio de información accesible en español: no somos un foro de discusión, formula buenas preguntas y recibe respuestas buenas y especificas, busca entre miles de preguntas y respuestas, contesta y edita el contenido del sitio para ayudarnos a mantener un sitio con relevancia y precisión alta.

**Video 2**: Cómo preguntar bien - dar ejemplos de buenas preguntas 

**a.** Preguntas especificas: se preciso en los que preguntas, incluye todo los detalles necesarios para poder reproducir el problema, no uses palabras o frases sin peso actual (ayúdenme por favor, les agradecería mucho, no se que hacer, se me seca el cerebro con este problema, etc.)

**b.** Mostrar ejemplos de buenas preguntas: no gastaremos tiempo viendo preguntas malas

**c.** Cómo aceptar una respuesta: el autor debe aceptar la respuesta que conteste la pregunta que se escribió.

**d.** Preguntas fuera de tema: las preguntas deben ser formuladas de tal forma que puedan recibir una respuesta directa, preguntas subjetivas o llenas de opiniones no se deben preguntar dado a que estas no tienen una respuesta, nos interesan las preguntas que tengan soluciones.

**Video 3**: Cómo contestar bien - dar ejemplos de buenas respuestas

**a.** Respuestas especificas: se preciso en los que respondas, incluye todo los detalles necesarios para compartir la solución el problema, no uses palabras o frases sin peso actual (espero y te ayude, a mi también, no se si te sirva, etc.)

**b.** Mostrar ejemplos de buenas preguntas: no gastaremos tiempo viendo respuestas malas


**c.** Los comentarios: se deben usar para pedir más explicaciones, para ayudar a los que formularon la pregunta a ser mas específicos y claros, para dejar notas sobre el proceso en cuestión

**Video 4**: Cómo usar el sitio efectivamente - las medallas, la reputación, la votación.

**a.** La reputación: que significa (una manera de medir tus logros y conocimiento), como se gana, como aumentar o perderla

**b.** Las medallas: como se ganan, que significan, donde se encuentra la lista de las medallas

**c.** Aceptar la respuesta a tu pregunta: es de suma importancia el aceptar la respuesta que resolvió tu problema, esto ayuda al sitio a mantenerse útil y ordenado, ayuda con puntos (reputación) a los que proporcionaron respuestas a tu pregunta

**d.** Los votos: no aceptamos comentarios insustanciales, puedes demostrar tu agradecimiento al votar a favor de lo que lees, de igual manera puedes votar en contra, la votación es la manera en que comunicamos la utilidad del contenido que encontramos en el sitio

**Video 5**: Cómo ser un buen miembro del sitio y cómo ayudarnos a crecer - usar enlaces para compartir información, correr la voz en redes sociales, etc.
**a.** El Respeto mutuo: nuestra comunidad depende de la manera en que nos tratamos como seres humanos, este sitio es más que solamente un repositorio de información porque tratamos con personas reales, ser cordiales y tener una actitud de ayudar al prójimo

**b.** Compartir enlaces: cada pregunta tiene su enlace y nos ayudaría mucho el poder correr la voz sobre este sitio para poder seguir ayudando a la gente que lo necesita

**c.** Divertirse y colaborar: como unirse al chat, a los webcasts, y los otros eventos que tendremos en un futuro y como sirven estas cosas en crear los vínculos fuertes de nuestra comunidad

Comment: dale! vamos con todo el power 2.0!

Comment: ¿Podríamos haber otros usuarios narrando los vídeos y que no solo @fredyfx haga todo el esfuerzo?

Comment: claro :D vamos colaborando entre todos, quién se anima!

Comment: ¡#2 y #3 son vitales!

Comment: ¿Quién se apunta entonces?

Comment: Yo me apunto...

Comment: El *problema* de la narración es que todos tenemos acentos diferentes y puede salir un vídeo muy raro... yo también me ofrezco a narrar.

Comment: entonces ahora necesitamos un guión, storyline :D

Comment: @fredyfx en seguida elaboro los punto del video

Comment: dale hermano! :D a con todo!

Comment: por cierto @JuanM te acabo de enviar un correo :D

Comment: Por favor, en la narración, utilicen un español neutro, sin modismos o regionalismos. Es mi opinión.

Comment: @miso despreocúpate, Perú tiene un español neutro y en lo personal me gusta expresarme de lo más claro posible, el video del Xamarin Dev Days es un buen ejemplo a excepción de la frase "sí brother!" que normalmente es utilizada en Perú. Gracias por el punto de vista :D

Comment: hey @Elenasys la palabra correcta es carisma :D charism es en inglés. Vamos con todo el power 2.0!!!

Comment: @fredyfx excellente FredyFX, a mostrar el carisma!  =D

Comment: Listas ya las explicaciones de los videos, favor de editar donde se necesite. :)

Comment: ¿Como va este proyecto, en que fase vamos?

Comment: Con 5 videos, sería un promedio de 18 minutos. ¿Se subirá los videos por separado o todo junto? ... Al principio, cuando yo leí la palabra introductorio, pensé que iba a ser la intro antes de cada webcast, pero ahora veo que estuve equivocado.

Comment: @ArtEze los videos se subirían por separado

Comment: [@JuanM](https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-7PvqiYTFXc8/W4CDDWR04LI/AAAAAAAADp8/7x6mHfrz1TohkNzu6AbD0tL0LK9gCFjaQCLcBGAs/s640/han-pasado-84-a%25C3%25B1os.jpg)

Comment: @JheymanMejia La verdad sí parece que ha pasado mucho tiempo.  Pero, estoy listo para apoyar esta iniciativa de la comunidad.  ¿Te animas a liderar este proyecto?

Comment: En lo que pueda colaborar, con todo el gusto.

Comment: @JheymanMejia puedes conectarte con FredyFx para ver cómo va todo y así poder renovar el interés de este proyecto. Lo puedes hacer [en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=es.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Me apunto al proyecto. Cuenten conmigo