# ¿Existe algún material adicional para compartir acerca de SOes? ¿Dónde se encuentran sus logos oficiales? ¿Hay reglas al respecto?

Tags: soporte, promoción-del-sitio

En estos días voy a dar una conferencia en un encuentro de software libre, entonces quería dar a conocer la comunidad. A más de mencionarla y colocar el logo, **¿existe algún material adicional para compartir acerca de la comunidad?**

Existía una publicación para hacer [vídeos introductorios de SOes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/899/video-introductorio-para-soes), si hay ese material sería interesante que lo compartieran para mostrar algo de eso.

**¿Dónde se encuentran los logos oficiales de la comunidad?**

En Stack Overflow inglés se encuentran en: https://stackoverflow.com/company/logos

Y otra pregunta: **¿Existen lineamientos o reglas para dar a conocer la comunidad?**

Comment: ....... Está [el póster](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/30872?m=34858930#34858930)

Comment: Genial @Mariano, lo colocaré en el material que estoy preparando :)

Comment: el video sigue en pendiente...  ><U Hice un audio donde sólo grabé voz pura

Comment: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1371/65